# Require assistance on stopping a timer when a slider change has occured

Tags: java, swing, timer, timertask, changelistener

I'm trying to create a animation by importing pictures from a sprite sheet and changing the speed using a timer. When I set the speed for the first time, it works perfectly, but anytime after that it wont change the speed. The previous speed will continue playing and I get this error in the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L82mB.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.
Here is what I have so far:

Edit: Found the problem for the timerTask & moved it into the ChangeListener, however, the speed still does not change when the slider moves.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class AnimationGUI {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private static JLabel value = new JLabel("0");
    private static JLabel image = new JLabel("");
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animation GUI");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1, 10, 1);

        slider.addChangeListener(new Slider());

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        panel.add(slider);
        panel.add(value);
        panel.add(image);
    }

    private static class Slider implements ChangeListener {

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(counter + ".png"));
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > 12) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }
            };

            if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                value.setText("" + (int) source.getValue());
                int speed = source.getValue() * 100;
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, speed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First recommendation, use a Swing `Timer` instead of a `TimerTask`, apart from been self contained and supporting things like `stop`, `start` and `restart`, it's also safe to use for updating the UI in Swing - Swing is not thread safe

Comment: Beat me to the punch -- use a `javax.swing.Timer` not a `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: I disagree with MadProgrammer. Swing Timers can really gunk up the EDT, and it's not *that* difficult to code in a way to avoid concurrency errors from cropping up. Performance will take a significant hit with Swing Timers. But, it is one of those agree-to-disagree situations. My current preference is to use the JavaFX AnimationTimer.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner So would `SwingUtiltities.invokeLater`, `synchronized` would also "clog" the EDT, but you are right, it's not ALWAYS the best solution, but in this case, I'd say it's simplest - At some point or another, you're going to have to get data from what other "thread" is been used over to the EDT in a manner which doesn't violate the single threaded nature of the API - I'd love to see how you'd apply a JavaFX `AnimationTimer` to Swing, as a comparison

Comment: Don't post images of text! Copy/paste the text itself as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: No going back! I really really prefer JavaFX at this point. Scheduling a one time task on the EDT is no big deal, but for an animation loop, it costs. I think there's a book, Killer Game Programming where the author compares a calculate game loop (using Thread.sleep), a Util timer and a Swing Timer. The Util and sleep-based (his pref) worked equally well, the Swing Timer was much worse in terms of performance. Java Concurrency In Practice (Goetz) recommends an ExecutorService, FixedThreadPool as more robust than Util.Timer, but many are intimidated.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Yes, but Swing `Timer` (and `SwingWorker`) both use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to schedule the updates, so unless you're violating the single threaded nature of the API, how else are you safely updating the properties of the UI? JavaFX works the same way (as I understand it) - possibly just more efficiently, given it will throw exceptions if you try and update the UI from outside the context it's event thread

Comment: It's a big topic and we are on the verge of provoking StackOverflow's "wouldn't you rather have a conversation" warning. It's agree-to-disagree, imho. The Goetz book (difficult read), or "Programming Concurrency on the JVM" (Subramaniam--an easier read) or  Functional Programming practices in general deal with concurrency-related problems.

Answer (score 2):

First recommendation, use a Swing `Timer` instead of a `TimerTask`, apart from been self contained and supporting things like `stop`, `start` and `restart`, it's also safe to use for updating the UI from - Swing is not thread safe

Something like...

```
private static class Slider implements ChangeListener {

    private Timer timer;

    public Slider() {
        timer = new Timer(16, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(counter + ".png"));
                counter++;
                if (counter > 12) {
                    counter = 0;
                }                    
            }
        });
        timer.start()
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
        JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            value.setText("" + (int) source.getValue());
            int speed = source.getValue() * 100;
            timer.setDelay(speed);
        }
    }
}
```

as an example

See [How to use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to cancel the existing TimerTask and start a new one with the desired speed.